# Show specific categories in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, show, categories

I have more than 800 categories, because 1 post may have more more than 10. I want to display only X categories on front page. How I can do this?

Comment: why can't you pass argument to display n number of categories ?

Comment: Because I want to display specific categories, not n number of them

Comment: Why don't you use a counter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$id = get_the_ID();
$cats = wp_get_post_categories($id);
$i=0;
foreach ( $cats as $cat ){
  if($i <10){
    //Dosomething with $cat
  }
  $i++;
}
```

By setting a counter you could show desired categories